# How to retrieve specific parts of the text? - grep/regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to retrieve specific information from a text file.:

```
Barnes and Kolling, 9780131976290,480, Pearson, Objects First with Java, LM002411,3989,781,true
Aho Sethi and Ullman, 9780201101942,795, Addison-Wesley, Compilers: Principles Techniques and Tools, LM002711,599,0,FALSE
Harvey Paul and Jeffrey, 9780130622211,1568, Prentice Hall, C# How to Program, LM002876,4599,45,TRUE
Muster, 9780072193145,1011, McGraw-Hill, Unix Made Easy: The Basics and Beyond (Made Easy), LM002468,6395,0,TRUE
Thomee, 9783540331216,370, Springer Verlag, Galerkin Finite Element Methods for Parabolic Problems, LM002153,4554,0,FALSE
```

the information to be retrieved:

> Objects First with Java

> Compilers: Principles Techniques and Tools

> C# How to Program

> Unix Made Easy: The Basics and Beyond (Made Easy)

> Galerkin Finite Element Methods for Parabolic Problems

Comment: Do you have any examples of books with commas in their titles? Like "Shell Programming in Unix, Linux and OS X"?

Comment: No, I have tried everything but it keeps randomly retrieving other information, I need to use only regular expression.

Comment: Wanting to use only regular expressions makes no sense here when that would be one of the more complicated ways of extracting that information.

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d , -f 5 FILE
```

will produce the results you require. This pulls the fifth column, separated by a comma delimiter.

Comment: Can you write one only using regular expression?

Comment: @The_Liner Is your task not to get the title of the books?

Comment: Is this a home work assignment?

Comment: Yes, I needed to use it in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution, assuming there is no embedded commas or newlines in the fields of your data, is to use `cut -d , -f 5 file`, possibly with  some post-processing to get rid of the initial blank characters that this would leave (`sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//'` would delete these).

Extracting the data with `grep` would not be possible unless you have a non-standard variant of `grep` that understands the `-o` option.  Standard `grep` only extracts matching *lines* from files.

Matching particular fields using regular expressions is fiddly, and often leads to unreadable (and therefore unmaintainable) code that break once a corner case are found.

In this case, it would be better to use a tool that knows how to divide the input into separate fields, like `cut` above, or `awk` (below).  If it turns out that your data is actually a CSV file, you may want to look at `csvkit` and its `csvcut` utility, because CSV is a structured format with special quoting and encoding rules that simple tools like `grep`, `sed`, and `awk` would be struggling to cope with.

---

```bsh
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '{ print $5 }' file
```

This **uses a regular expression** to specify what the delimiter is in your data (a comma followed by optional blanks).  The fifth such field is extracted and printed on each line.

This assumes that no field contains embedded commas (or newlines).

Given the input in the question, this would generate

```
Objects First with Java
Compilers: Principles Techniques and Tools
C# How to Program
Unix Made Easy: The Basics and Beyond (Made Easy)
Galerkin Finite Element Methods for Parabolic Problems
```

You could also use GNU `sed` like so:

```bsh
tr ',' '\n' <file | sed '5~9!d; s/^[[:blank:]]*//'
```

This simply replaces all commas with newlines, then prints every 9th line starting at line 5 (actually *deletes* every line that is not one of those lines, and prints the remaining lines).  A **regular expression is used** to trip out the initial blanks at the start of each line before printing them.

---

Just for fun:

Since you actually want the middle field of nine fields per line, we could strip off the first and last fields, and repeat that until there's nothing else left to strip off.

A field in the beginning can be removed using `s/^[^,]*,//` in `sed`, and a field at the end can be removed using `s/,[^,]*$//`.  The `t` command in `sed` branches to the given label if the most recent `s///` command made a change.  The `:` command introduces a label.

```
$ sed -e ': again' -e 's/^[^,]*,//; s/,[^,]*$//' -e 't again' -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' file
Objects First with Java
Compilers: Principles Techniques and Tools
C# How to Program
Unix Made Easy: The Basics and Beyond (Made Easy)
Galerkin Finite Element Methods for Parabolic Problems
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have the title followed by  `LM...`.  Here is the regex for you:

```
sed "s/\([^,]*, *\)\{4\}\(.*\), LM.*/\2/" booksdata
```

The data is contained in the file `booksdata`.
The regex `\([^,]*, *\)\{4\}` captures 4 instances of fields separated by `,` with an optional space at the end.  The use of `LM...` allows for the inclusion of a comma in the book title.